# Website is not responding when a handler is processing

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, threadpool, worker-process

In my web site I have a handler (GetFile.ashx) which, when executed, lets you download a file at a given download rate. The handler needs to be executing until the user finishes download. 
The problem is that while the handler is executing, other pages (and the handler itself) of the website are unreachable and IIS waits until the page have finished executing before responding to other requests.. How can I solve?

Another thing I noted is that I'm using IIS7 on a server on Amazon EC2... How can it be possible that IIS can only process one request at a time??

Thank you.

Comment: Same happens if I create a page with Thread.Sleep(1000000) and load it. All other pages are unreachable.

Comment: Same behaviour if someone is uploading something... all other pages become unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. If you use a page (or handleer) which implements IRequireSession,  will lock other pages from processing, because it will have an exclusive lock on the session. The solution is to create an handler which doesn't require session state.

Comment: That was the issue in my case.  I was using a httpclient in an aspx page to call a service that uses SignalR to communicate with a remote system & return a response.  Sometimes we have to wait on a reply (or not get one at all).  In my case, all of asp.net was frozen until the httpclient code completed or timed out, even using async/await with the PostAsync method.  Turns out, if i disable session state by using the EnableSessionState="false" page directive, the issue is solved.   Overlooking this seems like an easy way to introduce a ton of potential scalability issues if not really careful.

Answer (score 0):

Only a limited number of threads can be executing at the same time, it could be that you have used up all the available threads. You could try to implement a asynchronous HTTP handler instead, using `IHttpAsyncHandler`.

A walkthrough for creating a `IHttpAsyncHandler` exists at MSDN, see [Walkthrough: Creating an Asynchronous HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx).

EDIT:
You could also try to increase the number of concurrent requests, using:

```
<system.web>
  <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="24" />
</system.web>
```

See the discussion on the ASP.NET forum, http://forums.asp.net/t/1447626.aspx/1.

Comment: I'm the only user (because I'm testing it)... and I can only make one request per time, otherwise IIS won't reply until the other request have finished... how can it be possible that I'm using all the available threads?

Comment: Could you post the implementation?

Comment: You could also take a look at this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1447626.aspx/1. Which tells you how to increase the number of concurrent requests.